# Function Time Complexity

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity, code-complexity

hi read in a book that calling subroutines is considered to be a constant time operation, even if the subroutines itself does not execute in constant time, but depends on the input size.
Then if i have the following piece of code:

```
void func(int m){
int n = 10;
    subrout(m);//function which complexity depends on m
    subrout2(n);//function which complexity depends on n
}
```

i suppose i can consider func() to be a constant time function, e.g. O(1)?

and what if i have this:

```
void func(){
    int n = 10;
    Type object;
    object.member_method(n);/*member function which time complexity depends upon n*/
}
```

can i still consider func() a constant time function?
is there some case in which this rule falls ? 
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot consider `func(int m)` to have a constant time complexity. Its time complexity is `O(T1(m) + T2(10))`, where `T1` and `T2` are functions describing the time complexity of `subrout` and `subrout2`, respectively.

In the second case, the time complexity, technically, is constant.

As a general comment, the point of specifying time complexity with asymptotic notation is to describe how the number of operations increases as a function of input size.

Answer (score 0):

What the book probably meant to say is that time complexity of the calling function `T_func` is `T_call + T_callee`. Here `T_call` is the time operation of passing parameters and setting up the environment for the callee and `T_callee` is the time spent inside the subroutine. The book says is that it is safe to assume `T_call` is constant, while no such assumptions are made regarding `T_callee`.

To clarify assume we have a function `func` that calls one subroutine `callee`.

```
  func(s){
      callee(s);
  }
```

then `T_func(s) = T_call + T_callee(s)`. If `size(s) = n` and `T_callee = O(f(n))` then it is safe to say that `T_func = O(f(n))`.